# SSMS Job Failing - DTSX Package Timeout

Tags: ssis, timeout, sendmail, ssms

I have a job on SSMS that is a DTSX package in Visual Studio and in the last day it has started failing due to the following error. I cant find any timeout settings to extend the timeout either.

```
Date        26/08/2014 13:02:01
Log     Job History (JOB B)

Step ID     1
Server      SERVER A
Job Name        Job B
Step Name       1
Duration        00:02:26
Sql Severity        0
Sql Message ID      0
Operator Emailed        
Operator Net sent       
Operator Paged      
Retries Attempted       0

Message
Executed as user: DOMAINA\USERA. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package 
Utility  Version 9.00.3042.00 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. 
All rights reserved.    Started:  13:02:01  Error: 2014-08-26 13:04:26.70     
Code: 0xC002F304     Source: DTSTask_DTSSendMailTask_1 Send Mail Task     
Description: An error occurred with the following error message: 
"The operation has timed out.".  End Error  
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  
Started:  13:02:01  Finished: 13:04:26  Elapsed:  145.25 seconds.  
The package execution failed.  The step failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue that it was using a local account rather than a domain account.

Source that helped me resolve here: [DTSX package runs in Visual Studio but not when called from a Database Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040309/dtsx-package-runs-in-visual-studio-but-not-when-called-from-a-database-job)

Answer (score 0):

Check your SMTP Connection manager. You would have an attribute called **"Timeout(milliseconds)"**
that you can change and see if that helps. If that does not help,  you would need to check with your network guys why the SMTP server is not responding.

Comment: Where can i find this setting - SSMS or Visual Studio?

Comment: In Visual Studio. Check the Connection manager that your send mail task is using.

Comment: I cant find this setting at all in visual studio

Comment: I found the setting and extended the timeout setting, and still getting the issue, could there be an individual setting for timeout per dtsx package?

Comment: I guess then its an issue with your SMTP server.

Comment: Any idea where i could find the setting in that?

Comment: @Matt THe SMTP connection manager doesn't seem to have a Timeout attribute